# how to hide FBProfilepictureview

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimagepickercontroller

i get picture in FBProfilepicture view. I placed one button in this view.When button click show device photo and fetched image in button. but this image is placed in fbprofile picture view back side.please help.

```
- (IBAction)act_AddPhotoFacebLogin:(id)sender {

mPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mPicker.delegate = self;
mPicker.allowsEditing = YES;

   mPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:mPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
userProfileImage.frame = CGRectZero;

}
```

show image in my button
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

```
  [btn_ProfileFb1Picture setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

userProfileImage is a fbprofilepicture view and this view contain btn_ProfileFb1Picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBProfilepictureview is subClass of UIView and its also support hide property of UIView so just set it hide on your button click
if you have object like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *useProfileImage;
```

then set like this

```
useProfileImage.hidden = YES;
```

or you can do like

```
useProfileImage.frame = CGRectZero
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44927/discussion-between-user3152553-and-retro)